# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Odata configure datetime serialization to use Utc or omit Timezone

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Odata 7.3` in Asp.net Web Api Core 3.1 project.

It turns out that the lib adds TimeZone of the server to DateTimes from Ef output.

Ef itself returns data with `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.

So I expected the odata lib just to omit the TimeZone shift because webApi services behave this way.

The question is how to make odata not to add TimeZone of the server or return everything in utc(Z-format).

Tried to set it via NewtonSoft serializerSettings, but it doesn't work for OData endpoints

```
services.AddOData();

services.AddMvc(options => {options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;});

services
  .AddControllers()
  .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
                });
```

Thanks for help!

**Upd:** Setting DateTimeKind to Utc on Ef level(via `ValueConverter`s) allows server to convert datetime correctly to local. 
But still the datetime is returned not in Z-format but with local TimeZone of server.

Comment: Ran into this issue. I think it is idiotic to take a DateTime that is specified as UTC and output it as a DateTimeOffset in the servers timezone! Who gives a #(^& what timezone the server is in. The solution I went with was to switch to using DateTimeOffset everywhere and add ValueConverters to make sure I always get UTC DateTimeOffsets from EntityFramework. If that sounds like it would work for you I can write it up as an answer, but I do not have a solution using DateTimes with OData.

Comment: Dan, please try bort's suggestion `endpoints.SetTimeZoneInfo(TimeZoneInfo.Utc);`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

I have a similar setup (also treated timestamp as UTC on EF layer) and ran into the same issue.

In my case I was able to fix it with the following extension method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/mt135699(v=vs.118)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Example (Startup.cs)

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            if (odataRoutePrefix != null && edmModel != null)
            {
                endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection();
                endpoints.Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(100).Count().Select();
                endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", odataRoutePrefix, edmModel);
                endpoints.SetTimeZoneInfo(TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. It seems this extension method only exists in .NET Framework 4.x, and even there, the link is outdated, as the namespace changed from System.Web.OData.Extensions to Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions. More importantly, there's no `SetTimeZoneInfo` extension method in Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.dll 8.x, and there is no Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Extensions package.

Comment: There is SetTimeZoneInfo in ODataOptions. Almost everything moved to dependency services. See https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/2864bf9610b8e9c1907814e7c9c4673fcb3c5761/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/ODataOptions.cs#L137

Answer (score 3):

```
services.AddOData(options => options.TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

In OData v8 you can specify the timezone when configuring:

`program.cs`:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(options =>
{
    // set to use utc, and return Z instead of +00:00
    options.TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;

    options.AddRouteComponents("odata/", ODataModel.GetEdmModel())
        .Filter()
        ...
```

An alternate way which seems to work is to use a `DateTimeOffset` on the models instead of `DateTime`, but that seemed too invasive.

I also added EF value converter which sets the `Kind` when reading from the database, but this had no effect on the output of `OData`.